# Biopython and retrieving journal's full name

Tags: python-3.x, biopython, pubmed

I am using Biopython with Python 3.x to conduct searches from PubMed-database. I get the search results correctly, but next I would need to extract all the journal names (full names, not just abbreviations) of the search results. Currently I am using the following code:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline

Entrez.email = "my_email@gmail.com"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="search_term", retmax=20)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()

idlist = record["IdList"]

records = list(records)

for record in records:
    print("source:", record.get("SO", "?"))
```

So this works fine, but record.get("SO"), "?") returns only the abbreviation of the journal (for example, *N Engl J Med*, not *New England Journal of Medicine*). From my experiences with manual PubMed-searches, you can search using both the abbreviation or the full name, and PubMed will handle those in the same way, so I figured if there is also some parameter to get the full name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So this works fine, but record.get("SO"), "?") returns only the abbreviation of the journal

No it doesn't.  It won't even run due to this line:

```
records = list(records)
```

as `records` isn't defined.  And even if you fix that, all you get back from:

```
idlist = record["IdList"]
```

is a list of numbers like: `['17510654', '2246389']` that are intended to be passed back via an `Entrez.efetch()` call to get the actual data.  So when you do `record.get("SO", "?")` on one of these number strings, your code blows up (again).

First, the `"SO"` field abbreviation is defined to return Journal Title Abbreviation (TA) as part of what it returns.  You likely want `"JT"` Journal Title instead as defined in [MEDLINE/PubMed Data Element (Field) Descriptions](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/mms/medlineelements.html).  But neither of these has anything to do with this lookup.

Here's a rework of your code to get the article title and the title of the journal that it's in:

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "my_email@gmail.com"  # change this to be your email address
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="cancer AND wombats", retmax=20)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()

for identifier in record['IdList']:
    pubmed_entry = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=identifier, retmode="xml")
    result = Entrez.read(pubmed_entry)
    article = result['PubmedArticle'][0]['MedlineCitation']['Article']

    print('"{}" in "{}"'.format(article['ArticleTitle'], article['Journal']['Title']))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
"Of wombats and whales: telomere tales in Madrid. Conference on telomeres and telomerase." in "EMBO reports"
"Spontaneous proliferations in Australian marsupials--a survey and review. 1. Macropods, koalas, wombats, possums and gliders." in "Journal of comparative pathology"
>
```

Details can be found in the document: [MEDLINE PubMed XML Element Descriptions](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/licensee/elements_descriptions.html)